# how to import csv dataset into postgres. I tried solution on other pages but they are not working

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

My query:

```
copy public.bank from "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\Desktop\bankdetails.csv" DELIMITER ',' , csv HEADER;
```

Error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\Desktop\bankdetails.csv""
> LINE 1: copy public.bank from "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\Desktop\bankdetai...

[image]

Comment: Use single quotes for strings. Double quotes are for identifiers (names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me following command helped in psql shell. The error i was getting was because sql file had ANSI characters which are invisible in UTF8. you can remove such character in notepad++ then run command

```
psql -h localhost -d databasename -U username-f "c://path_to_file.sql"
```